# Decl macro not matching hardcoded value once token is consumed as literal?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm writing a TT muncher decl macro for parsing regular expressions.

An example of the syntax I'm using is as follows:

```
regex!(a b c ( a b c )) // equivalent to r"abc(abc)"
regex!('n' s o m e t h i n g) // equivalent to r"\nsomething"
```

For this I need to consume either `$char:ident` or `$char:literal` to match a character or escaped character respectively.

I've encountered an issue, however. It seems that once a token is matched as a literal, it can no longer be matched against a hardcoded value.

Here is a reproducable example on rustc 1.69.0:

```rs
macro_rules! is_a {
    ('a') => {"Found literal a"};
    ($any:literal) => {"Not literal a?"};
    (a) => {"Found ident a"};
    ($any:ident) => {"Not ident a?"};
}

macro_rules! to_lit {
    ($any:literal) => {is_a!($any)};
}

macro_rules! to_ident {
    ($any:ident) => {is_a!($any)};
}

fn test() {

    println!("{}", is_a!('a')); // Found literal a
    println!("{}", is_a!(a)); // Found ident a
    println!("{}", to_lit!('a')); // Not literal a?
    println!("{}", to_ident!(a)); // Found ident a
}
```

I can get around this by using a different syntax, but I'm very confused why it's happening in the first place. Can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the reference:

> #### [Forwarding a matched fragment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#forwarding-a-matched-fragment)
>
> When forwarding a matched fragment to another macro-by-example, matchers in the second macro will see an opaque AST of the fragment type. The second macro can't use literal tokens to match the fragments in the matcher, only a fragment specifier of the same type. The `ident`, `lifetime`, and `tt` fragment types are an exception, and *can* be matched by literal tokens. The following illustrates this restriction:
>
> ```rust
> macro_rules! foo {
>     ($l:expr) => { bar!($l); }
> // ERROR:               ^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
> }
>
> macro_rules! bar {
>     (3) => {}
> }
>
> foo!(3);
> ```
>
> The following illustrates how tokens can be directly matched after matching a `tt` fragment:
>
> ```rust
> // compiles OK
> macro_rules! foo {
>     ($l:tt) => { bar!($l); }
> }
>
> macro_rules! bar {
>    (3) => {}
> }
>
> foo!(3);
> ```

There is no workaround sadly; the only solution is to use proc-macros.

Comment: Also described in the Little Book of Rust Macros here: https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/minutiae/metavar-and-expansion.html, though the example from the reference is more concise IMO.

Comment: Unfortunate that there’s no workaround. I think I can use a sort of pre processor to add a unique prefix before any literals so I can match that instead and never directly consume a :literal. Thanks for the info!